# Writing on image to convert image to read only

Tags: c#, image, dispose

I have written a handler and a function to send watermark response back. But some how the image changes to read only.

I have disposed all the object.

The codes are as below:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
  var imagePath = QueryString.getValueOf("ID");
  var watermark = QueryString.getValueOf("watermark");
  context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(imagePath) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(watermark))
  {
    var originalImage = Image.FromFile(context.Server.MapPath("Images/NoImage.jpg"));
    originalImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    originalImage.Dispose();
  }
  else
  {
    if (watermark == "0")
    {
      var absolutePath = context.Server.MapPath(imagePath);
      var fileexist = System.IO.File.Exists(absolutePath);
      if (fileexist)
      {
        var originalImage = Image.FromFile(absolutePath);
        originalImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        originalImage.Dispose();
      }
      else
      {
        var originalImage = Image.FromFile(context.Server.MapPath("Images/NoImage.jpg"));
        originalImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        originalImage.Dispose();
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (imagePath.ToUpper().Contains(".GIF"))
      {
        var absolutePath = context.Server.MapPath(imagePath);
        var fileexist = System.IO.File.Exists(absolutePath);
        if (fileexist)
        {
          var originalImage = Image.FromFile(absolutePath);
          originalImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
          originalImage.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
          var originalImage = Image.FromFile(context.Server.MapPath("Images/NoImage.jpg"));
          originalImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
          originalImage.Dispose();
        }
      }
      else
      {
        var absolutePath = context.Server.MapPath(imagePath);
        var fileexist = System.IO.File.Exists(absolutePath);
        if (fileexist)
        {
          var originalImage = Image.FromFile(absolutePath);
          originalImage = new ImageMethods().AddWatermarkText(originalImage);
          originalImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
          originalImage.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
          var originalImage = Image.FromFile(context.Server.MapPath("Images/NoImage.jpg"));
          originalImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
          originalImage.Dispose();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the function is to writing images is as follows

```
public Image AddWatermarkText(Image img)
{
  try
  {
    var textOnImage = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["textOnImage"];
    var opacity = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["opicity"]);
    var red = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["red"]);
    var green = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["green"]);
    var blue = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["blue"]);
    var fontSize = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fontSize"]);
    var fontName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fontName"];

    var lobFromImage = Graphics.FromImage(img);
    var lobFont = new Font(fontName, fontSize, FontStyle.Regular);
    var lintTextHw = lobFromImage.MeasureString(textOnImage, lobFont);
    var lintTextOnImageWidth = (int)lintTextHw.Width;
    var lintTextOnImageHeight = (int)lintTextHw.Height;
    var lobSolidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(opacity, Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue)));

    var posLeft = (img.Width - lintTextOnImageWidth) / 2;
    posLeft = posLeft > 0 ? posLeft : 5;
    var lobPoint = new Point(posLeft, (img.Height / 2) - (lintTextOnImageHeight / 2));

    //  var lobPoint = new Point(RandomNumber(0, img.Width - lintTextOnImageWidth), RandomNumber(0, img.Height - lintTextOnImageHeight));
    lobFromImage.DrawString(textOnImage, lobFont, lobSolidBrush, lobPoint);

    lobFromImage.Dispose();
    lobSolidBrush.Dispose();
    lobFont.Dispose();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    HavException = true;
    ExceptionMessage = ex.Message;
  }
  return img;
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I don't know why it worked but it is working.

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var imagePath = QueryString.getValueOf("ID");
            var watermark = QueryString.getValueOf("watermark");
            string lstrResponseType;
            //  context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(imagePath) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(watermark))
            {
                using (var originalImage = Image.FromFile(context.Server.MapPath("Images/NoImage.jpg")))
                {
                    originalImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    originalImage.Dispose();
                }
                lstrResponseType = "image/jpeg";
            }
            else
            {

                var absolutePath = context.Server.MapPath(imagePath);
                var fileexist = System.IO.File.Exists(absolutePath);
                if (!fileexist)
                {
                    var originalImage = Image.FromFile(context.Server.MapPath("Images/NoImage.jpg"));
                    originalImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    lstrResponseType = "image/jpeg";
                    originalImage.Dispose();
                }
                else
                {
                    using (var originalImage = Image.FromFile(absolutePath))
                    {

                        if (watermark == "0")
                        {
                            originalImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                            lstrResponseType = "image/jpeg";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (imagePath.ToUpper().Contains(".GIF"))
                            {
                                originalImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Gif);
                                lstrResponseType = "image/gif";
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                new ImageMethods().AddWatermarkText(originalImage);
                                originalImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                                lstrResponseType = "image/jpeg";

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            context.Response.ContentType = lstrResponseType;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have an exception before your Dispose call then your images won't be disposed and files will remain locked. You should put calls to Dispose in "finally" section or use "using" like:

```
using (var originalImage = Image.FromFile(absolutePath))
  originalImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Also to avoid locking you can read file to stream first and then create image from stream

```
using(var imageStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
  return Image.FromStream(imageStream );
```

Comment: thanks for your response. What you are saying is write. But the above code locking the file without any exception.

Comment: You can also try to load image files to streams first and then create an image from strem. I added sample to my answer